# find the variable which is equal to the value of another variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I came across a confusing fact during coding a script.

How can i find the variable which is equal to the value of another variable. THEN , get the value of that variable.

Here's an example:

```
var result;
var 1 = "john";
var 2 = "amy";
var 3 = "micheal";

var info = "1";
```

When var info is set to `1` , the script will then look for variable 1 which has the value `JOHN` then get the value `john` . Then set the result's value to "john".

For the same thing ,

When var info is set to `2` , the script will then look for variable 2 which has the value `AMY` then get the value `amy` . Then set the result's value to "amy".

and so on..

My info variable's value is not determined. it could be 1 , 2 or 3 which is set/determined by an user event.

P/S i can use if and else , but i want to know how this can be done. :)

So how can i do this?

Comment: Are those even valid variable names in JS?

Comment: Have you considered using an array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to do something very different:

```
var result;

var names = {
  '1': 'john',
  '2': 'amy',
  '3': 'michael'
};

var info = "1";
result = names[info];
```

That will put 'john' into `result`.

You see, this defines something called a "lookup table", and saves it into `names`. Then, you can use a "key" (in your case: 1, 2, 3) to look up a value. Writing `names[info]` looks inside `info`, and gets its value, which in the above example is `"1"`. It then looks for the key `"1"` inside `names`, and sees that the value for `"1"` is `'john'`.

I know this isn't exactly what you were asking about, but I suspect it might help.

Comment: If you are only using numbers, you can use an array instead: `var names = ['john', 'amy', 'michael'];`.

Comment: Yup! Just remember that if you use an array, then the first item is automatically `0`, the second is `1`, the third is `2`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Numbers aren't legal variable names, but you can use a bit of evil to do what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/2mAeh/2/ (only tested in Safari).  **Just to be clear, I don't recommend this.  It is evil.**

```
var result;
var a = "amy";
var b = "john";
var c = "micheal";
var info = "a";

var variable = eval("info"); // just to satisfy your requirement, same as info
result = eval(variable);

alert(variable + ' = ' + result);
```

A better way to handle this would be with a map, using your "variable names" as the keys.  In this case you could use numbers as the keys, but I'll use the same keys as my other example for consistency.

```
var map = { "a": "Amy", "b" : "John", "c" : "micheal" };
var info = "a";

alert( info + ' = ' + map[info] );
```

Comment: It doesn't give you `a` only it's value. see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2mAeh/3/)

Comment: That still don't let you change `a`. only it's value. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2mAeh/4/)

Comment: @gdoron - he didn't ask to change `a`.  He asked to set `result` to the value of `a`.

Comment: You're right, and almost the only one who answered his question. +1.

Answer (score 1):

Using `window[var]`:

```
one = 'two';

two = '1';

alert(window[one]); // Alerts: 1
```

Comment: Ooh, hoisting! Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think that'll only work in global scope, and not in a function. (And +1 for the great point!)

Comment: @scraimer. no `hoisting` involved. and it will work only in the global scope indeed.

Comment: Ah, yes. Bit of a limitation there.

Comment: I expected that to work for me, too, but I couldn't (easily) make it work in a fiddle.  That could be because it was running in an iframe.

Answer (score 0):

> So how can i do this?

**You can NOT.**(out of the box)
You can not know the variables names only their values.

If you **really** wants to do it, and wanna pay it with  a spaghetti code, take a look at this:
[Get variable name. javascript "reflection"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9795773/601179)

or use `eval` as suggested by @tvanfosson to get the variable **value**, which is dangerous and deprecated.

---

- Note that variables in `javascript` can't begin with a number. `var 1 = "john";` => **invalid**

[**javscript variables names rules**](http://www.codelifter.com/main/tips/tip_020.shtml)

Answer (score 0):

Like this,

```
function findVariableByName(info){// info is 1, 2, 3

var result;
this['1'] = "john";
this['2'] = "amy";
this['3'] = "micheal";
result = this[info];
alert(result);
return result;
}

findVariableByName(1);
```

**Update:**

If you change your code like below and if it is in global scope,

<strike>var result;</strike>
<strike>var 1 = "john";</strike>
 <strike>var 2 = "amy";</strike>
<strike>var 3 = "micheal";</strike>
 <strike>var info = "1";</strike>

```
var one = 'john';
var two = 'amy';
var three = 'micheal';
var info = 'one';
```

You can do,

```
window[info] // gives you john
```

Answer (score 0):

You do this by setting up an object:

```
// Store your object
var obj = {result: null, a: "john", b: "amy", c: "michael", info: "1"}

// Iterate like so.  
    for(var key in obj) {
        if(obj[key] == info){
          alert(key);
        }
    }
```

I have not checked this code but it should work.  Good luck!