# How to know the name of a variable in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get variable name. javascript “reflection”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9795773/get-variable-name-javascript-reflection)

Is there a way to know the name of a variable?

Example:

```
var a = 1;
var b = 4;

function getName(param){
    //What should I return here?
}
```

What I want to do, is to have `getName` return "a" if I call `getName(a)`and return "b" if I call `getName(b)`

Is this possible?

Comment: I think you can only do this by comparison of the values and returning a string based upon that.

Comment: @gdoron - I like that question, but as noted, I would be careful of its use :) so "sort of" is the answer here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could alter the prototype of the object to add a function to do this, as described in this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/332429/1028949):

```
Object.prototype.getName = function() { 
   var funcNameRegex = /function (.{1,})\(/;
   var results = (funcNameRegex).exec((this).constructor.toString());
   return (results && results.length > 1) ? results[1] : "";
};
```

Comment: Extending `Object.prototype` is a **bad thing**. It breaks all kind of stuff since scripts usually assume that iterating over an object defined e.g. via an object literal does not yield any functions unless they were defined in that literal.

Comment: @ThiefMaster, you are correct and I wouldn't recommend or use this, either.  I am simply providing an answer to the question "Is there a way..."

Comment: Doesn't seem to work: `var blah = 'moo'; (function(lol){print(lol.getName());})(blah);` => `String`. I think the OP wants the **variable name**, not the constructor name. Even though he did accept the answer...

Answer (score 4):

No, that's not possible in a clean way and I highly doubt there is a useful use-case for this.

Comment: It's possible... somehow... http://stackoverflow.com/q/9795773/601179

Comment: I think I must be dense, but I can't see how the answer you're citing works. To me, it just seems like it gives you the formal parameter name ('x' in the linked example, 'param' in the OPs example).

Comment: Yeah, that answer returns the name of the constructor function.

Answer (score -1):

**It isn't possible to get variable name**. But you can get name of variable, who got exactly this value (**if you got some vairables with equal values, you get first defined**). And this function works only for global variables.

```
var a = 1;
var b = 4;

function test(value) {
  for (var x in window)
    if (window[x] === value)
      return x;
}

alert(test(b));
```

Comment: What if there are two variables with the same value?

Comment: Two?? I have thousands of variables that may have the same value...

Comment: As I tell, you can't get variable name, you get only name of variable, who is equal to given value.