# Accessing custom defined variable/object in javascript in for...in loop

Tags: javascript, loops

Let me explain the whole problem. I was trying to avoid writing this as it could be a long explanation.

I am working with a tool called Lectora. This is an authoring tool which generates HTML pages and SCORM compliant packages to be deployed to the LMS.

When I insert a button in the Lectora, the code that is generated is something like this...

```
<script>
// some code here...

button63 = new ObjButton('button63', ....);
button63.setImages('images/btn_next_en.png','images/btn_next_en.png','images/btn_next_mouseover_en.png');
button63.build();

button64 = new ObjButton('button64', ....);
button64.setImages('images/btn_back_en.png','images/btn_back_en.png','images/btn_back_mouseover_en.png');
button64.build();

button65897 = new ObjButton('button65897', ....);
button65897.setImages('images/btn_submit_en.png','images/btn_submit_en.png','images/btn_submit_mouseover_en.png');
button65897.build();

// some more code here...

</script>
```

So I try to write:

```
<script>
var arr_buttons = [];
for(var i in window)
{
if(window[i] typeof object)
{
    if(window[i] != null)
    {
        if(window[i] instanceof ObjButton)
        {
            arr_buttons.push(i);
        }
    }
}
}

alert(arr_buttons.length); // gives me  845 in IE11 and it gives me 44 in IE8
</script>
```

And when I check the contents of arr_buttons in console or by any other method, I do not find button65897 of any other button object in it. Which makes me think that it is not iterated at all!! This is my problem.

ObjButton is a Lectora created javascript object and I cannot edit it.

Now, I have set the language option in another variable and depending on the variable value for language, I want to get hold of the object 'button65897' and change its images. Now I am finding it difficult to get hold of 'button65897' in IE8.

Isn't there any way to get hold of the object 'button65897' in IE8?

Comment: Whatever you're doing - use an ARRAY instead of numbered variables!!!

Comment: I am not writing that code. That code is generated by the tool itself. So I have no control over how the variables are named.

All I am doing is writing the second part of the code to access those variables.

Comment: OK, now that I've actually read your question - change the tool. Or add a step that rewrites the outputted code to use an array.

Comment: No I have to work with this tool. Neither can I change the code that creates the output. Bacically I have to work within these parameters and make it work in IE8. Any ideas?