# Insert key and object in Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to insert key & Object in array.

JQuery code:

```
  var steps = [];
  var RequestParams = {};
  RequestParams.ActionName = 'aname';
  steps.push({ Name:'abc'} ,RequestParams);
```

My output

```
"steps": [
            { "Name": "abc" },
            {  
             ActionName :"aname"
             },
  ]
```

Expected:

```
"steps": [
            { "Name": "abc",
            "RequestParams": {
             ActionName :"aname"
             },
  ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
steps.push({"Name": "abc", "RequestParams": RequestParams});
```

What you want to achieve is having inside your `steps` array a javascript object with a property `Name` that has value `"abc"`, and a property named `RequestParams` that has the value of your `RequestParams`variable.

Comment: Is it possible without hard coding?

Comment: @user3194721 what do you mean by "hard coding"? What are you using then?

Comment: I'd say no, AFAIK javascript doesn't have any reflection mechanism to use the name of the variable inside a script, so you have to hardcode the `RequestParam` name of the property. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9795773/get-variable-name-javascript-reflection

Answer (score 0):

Should be

```
steps.push({ Name:'abc' } ,{ RequestParams:RequestParams });
```