# JS - Override console.log to show "object: object" of logged object?

Tags: javascript, console.log

How can I override the `log` method of the `console` object in order to turn this:

```
//objectXYZ: {prop: 1}
console.log(objectXYZ);
==> {prop: 1}
```

Into this:

```
//objectXYZ: {prop: 1}
console.log(objectXYZ);
==> objectXYZ: {prop: 1}
```

So I could save time and instead of typing `console.log("object: ",object);`, I would only type `console.log(object);`

Any ideas?

Comment: A function has no way of knowing the name of the variable that you are passing to it, and at any rate, you shouldn't be trying to modify the console object.

Comment: Parameters passed to functions do not come along with their names.

Comment: [Entirely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602141/variable-name-as-a-string-in-javascript) [impossible](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9795773/1048572) in JavaScript.

Comment: You would have to change your calling method to something like: `func({name:'objectXYZ',value:objectXYZ})`